Restricted form
I want to create a fillable electronic form for people to write a career plan. This is for incarcerated people. Therefore, once they write the plan, I want staff to take the e-form back so people can’t use it for contraband communication (by sharing credentials).
When needed, I want staff to give the form back so it is write able and take it back again when done.
Does anything like this exist? If it needed to be developed, are there any suggestions for a place to start?

Are you familiar with Google forms? There is an option to send a copy back to people who fill it out
